# How to expire/remove current access token on generating new one?

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0

How can I revoke/remove/expire already issued access token on generating new one in oAuth 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the token... damn, this *it depends* thing seems to be recurrent in software development!

If you have an opaque token, just some random number of bits that in theory are unique and as such it is acceptable to assume that no one will be able to guess it, then you need to maintain a list of expired tokens and then each time someone tries to use a token, you'll need to check this blacklist.

On the other end, if you're talking about self-contained tokens (aka bearer tokens) that usually appear in the good-looking JWT format then you have different options. You can still use the blacklist approach, so that's one. Additionally, since these tokens are signed to prevent the data contained within from being tampered by an attacker (check [Get started with JWT's](https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/)), you can also change signing keys. Bear in mind that in most occasions, you'll use the same signing keys across a lot of tokens, so this second options ends up not being feasible most of the time.

Finally, mandatory read on this topic: [OAuth 2.0 Token Revocation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009)